# "This call is ambigious between the following methods...." when generating client via swashbuckler for ASP.Net core 2.1

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm attempting to use swashbuckle/swagger for the first time and im encountering a bit of a snag where swashbuckle is used to generate the swagger.json file, and swagger then builds the client off of that, but importing both packages results in an ambiguous call, and if i try to specify the call it doesn't register the path of the call as valid.

specifically app.UseSwagger(); gets flagged as the ambiguous call and nswag.aspnetcore and swashbuckle.aspnetcore are the packages.

In short - How do i specify which package I want for the call OR is there a way to avoid the conflict all together? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you’re referencing both Swashbuckle and NSwag, these libraries will both produce Swagger/OpenApi output for you so you should only use one or the other. You can remove the reference to one from your project to fix the problem, as you’ve not posted any code I can’t be sure which one you should remove and how much cleanup you’ll need to do.

NSwag has more support for creating client code so you may want to keep using this, more info if you haven’t already seen it for using NSwag with aspnet core is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio%2Cvisual-studio-xml)

Comment: That is it exactly, I was having trouble getting nswag to generate a .json file and based on some documentation i was following swashbuckle should do that, but I suppose that's a separate problem from this one now. Thanks!

Comment: Great, no problem